# anybody knows a short if version for the following snippet?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if(isset($_GET['tag'])) { 
  define("NJ_THISCATSUB","tag: ".$_GET['tag']);
}
```

Comment: This might be because I've never used php, but I don't know what the question is

Comment: `"tag:$_GET[tag]"` for a microscopic code "savings".

Answer (score 3):

There may be a couple of ways, none of which would really be recommended instead of what you have.

Except for omitting the `{}` you can't really shorten by packing it into a ternary operator (for example) if `NJ_THISCATSUB` is assumed to be ***not defined*** when `$_GET['tag']` is unset.  Stick with what you have  -it is clear and readable, and correct.

```
// About as short as you're going to get:
// In other words, your method is fine and I don't recommend changing it.
if(isset($_GET['tag'])) define("NJ_THISCATSUB","tag: ".$_GET['tag']);
```

#### Ternary example:

However, `NJ_THISCATSUB` were defined as a null or empty value in absence of the `$_GET['tag']`, you could use a ternary:

```
// Define as NULL, absent $_GET['tag'] (not the same as what you have!)
define('NJ_THISCATSUB', isset($_GET['tag']) ? "tag: ".$_GET['tag'] : NULL);
```

This doesn't appear to be the behavior you are after though.

---

#### By short-circuit `&&`

You could take advantage of the logical `&&` and to it this way, saving a couple of characters. If the left side of `&&` is true, it proceeds to check the right side, and must evaluate the `define()` to do so. If the left side is `FALSE`, it will short circuit and not evaluate the right. Therefore this works:

```
isset($_GET['tag']) && define("NJ_THISCATSUB","tag: ".$_GET['tag']);
```

*The above is kind of unconventional in PHP though* (if there is a such thing as convention in PHP), and would be more at home in languages like JavaScript or Ruby.  You're far more likely to encounter PHP code using the simpler `if ()` you initially posted.

```
// Simple console demonstration
// Define X if $x is set:
php > $x = 123;
php > isset($x) && define('X', $x);
php > echo X;
// 123

// Define Y if $y is set (it isn't)...
php > isset($y) && define('Y', $y);
php > echo Y;
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant Y - assumed 'Y' in php shell code on line 1

Notice: Use of undefined constant Y - assumed 'Y' in php shell code on line 1
// Oops, Y is not defined as a constant...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can allow a half-filled constant:

```
define("NJ_THISCATSUB", @"tag: $_GET[tag]");
```

Note that this only makes sense if may want to debug the absent input parameter later on. With `isset` it's gone forever, with [`@()`](http://php.net/) you can bring notices back.

Also note that absent array key quotes are only permissable in double quoted string context.